# "Positive definite" matrix for component-wise positive vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, copositivity

Is there a condition such that a symmetric matrix is "positive definite" for any component-wise positive vector?

There is a matrix $A$, and $A \in S^n$, $S$ denotes the real symmetric matrix set. What's the condition for $x^T A x > 0$, and $x \in R^n$, $|x| \neq 0$, and $x \succeq 0$ (component-wise positive).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Look up copositive matrices.   A matrix $A$ is copositive if $x^{T}Ax \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Is it necessary condition as well?

Comment: This is a a definition, so "A matrix $A$ is copositive *if and only if* ..." is implied.

Comment: Thank you again! Appreciate it.